# What is a delegate in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been flashing through some questions here about xcode iOS programming, and I've seen more and more people say something like "as the delegate of blabla" things like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    currentLocationAnnotation = [annotation retain];
}
```

But I could never help me because I don't understand what this means, and where I have to put it, if I put it in my .m file, it doesn't work, and if I put it in my AppDelegate.m it doesn't work either.

Please help :)

Comment: Study the Cocoa Touch conceptual documentation. You'll quickly find out what the delegation model is and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code this is the  custom delegate what it means it just work like a helper object in which whatever methods had implemented inside custom delegates can be used.

Answer (score 0):

It's a design pattern where you register a object(the delegate), that confirms to a specified protocol, with another instance of some other class that then calls the first objects "protocol methods"(delegate methods) when it wants the delegate to perform some work. This is usually used to avoid unnecessary subclassing when a object just wants to "outsource" part of it's work.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit hard to get in the beginning. A delegate of a class is like the handler of events of that class. For example, for the map view class, you set a delegate (e.g. your custom class), and in your custom class, start implementing the handlers (it doesn't necessarily need to handle events. For example table view asks its delegate about how many rows it will have, their height etc.). For example, in the example code you've posted, the map view is asking its delegate to return the view for the annotation object that it's sending as a parameter. You need to implement your logic in your class to return the appropriate object.

In English terms, think of it as an email: *'Hello, my delegate, as a part of your job, I'd like you to give me the view for annotation that I'm attaching below, Thanks, Map View.'*

Of course, it requires an immediate response from the delegate right now, and the 'attached below' is the 'annotation' parameter. Hope it helps.